# one to one relationship between two models?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following Model classes (I am using EF code first to generate the tables).

```
public class MyClass
{
    ....
    [Required, ForeignKey("Address")]
    public int Address1Id { get; set; }
    virtual public Address Address1 { get; set; }
    [Required, ForeignKey("Address")]
    public int Address12d { get; set; }
    virtual public Address Address2 { get; set; }
    [Required, ForeignKey("Address")]
    public int Address3Id { get; set; }
    virtual public Address Address3 { get; set; }
    ....
}
public class Address { .... }
```

I wish the create view of `MyClass` shows all the address fields and the addresses will be saved in the table Address first when saving the `MyClass`. But the scaffolding generated a DropDownList box for the addresses. How to modify the code to make it acting like these address fields are coded in the class `MyClass` directly and let the controller to save the addresses in table `Address` and `AddressID` in table `MyClass`?

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address1Id, "Address")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Address1Id", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address1Id)
    </div>
```

**Update:**
I tried to create the following ViewModel, but the scaffolding complain there is no key defined in the class.

```
public class DealViewModel
{
    public Deal Deal { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: is this an MVC or EF problem.   MVC can use such models.  EF expects a  type suitable for a key.  Complex types are suitable as DB keys. What were you hoping to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Your foreign key attributes are not correct:

```
[Required, ForeignKey("Address1")]
...
[Required, ForeignKey("Address2")]
...
[Required, ForeignKey("Address3")]
...
```

(And `Address12d` is a typo I guess)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking how to flatten out the model for an edit/create view in MVC. You don't want to have to create a Person, and then go create an Address, but instead create it in one screen. If that's what you're asking, yes you can do it! In fact, doing what you want is as simple as changing your create view to something like:

```
<h3>Address 1</h3>
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Address1)
<h3>Address 2</h3>
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Address2)
...etc
```

By default, MVC is smart enough to guess what an 'editor' for your `Address` should look like. Text fields for strings, checkboxes for bools, etc. If your `[HttpPost]` controller looks something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Person person)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var context = new AppDbContext();
        context.People.Add(person);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(personViewModel);
}
```

If you examine `person` in the debugger you should see that the `Address` properties are all filled in. Yup, the MVC ModelBinder is that smart! You shouldn't have to do anything else.

**Note:** As you progress in your project and your data model inevitably becomes more complex, you may run into problems passing model objects back and forth from controller to view. I strongly recommend following a pattern of using ViewModels, which are plain objects that represent a 'model' for the view, that is, it should bundle up all of the data going to and from the client. This will allow you to flatten out your data model and only include the fields you actually need. You might not need to use this pattern for this particular example, but it will be helpful in the future.

Hope this helps!